# C# and MongoDB - Return the updated document with UpdateOneAsync()

Tags: c#, mongodb, updates

I am a bit new to MongoDB driver 2.0 of C# and, I can't find the way to get the result of the updated document in my generic update function.

For the moment I have the following:

```
public async Task<T> UpdateAsync(T dataModel)
{
    string serializedDataModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataModel, new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
    });
    await GetCollection<T>().UpdateOneAsync(Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(s => s.Id, dataModel.Id), new BsonDocument() { { "$set", BsonDocument.Parse(serializedDataModel) } });
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedDataModel);
}
```

However the result returned is only the updated value I am giving, I would like the current database result.

I found some answers that were referring `FindOneAndModify`, however I couldn't find any `FindOneAndModifyAsync`.

Thanks forany help !

Comment: The modern API method is [`FindOneAndUpdate()`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_FindOneAndUpdate__1.htm) or [`FindOneAndUpdateAsync()`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_FindOneAndUpdateAsync__1.htm) Methods like `UpdateOne()` and variants do not return the document, only a result object which says what was matched and updated and some other stats. But not the document content. This is by design. The `FindAndModify` *direct* usage is deprecated.

Comment: It's not really a duplicate tho, in this question (that i mention in my question), it's about the previous version of the driver, not the async one :/ Thanks for your answer tho, can you tell me how can I get the "match/update" properties of the result? Or how to access it please :)

Comment: It's a duplicate if it's answered the same way. And it is. There are links to the API documentation where you can "find" the methods.

Comment: Thanks for your help Neil :)